# Property not defined for this namespace using a composite application

Tags: properties, namespaces, wsdl, xpages, composite-component

I have created a composite application containing a view and an xpage.
when the user select a document I publish the unid of the selected document to the xpage. this works fine using a component.

Now, in addition to this when I click an action in the view I want to publish another unid value to the xpage. so I do this using Lotusscript and the following code.

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim pb As NotesPropertyBroker
Set pb = s.GetPropertyBroker()
Call pb.setPropertyValue("Unid","Test")
Call pb.Publish()
```

When I run this code I get the following error

"Property not defined for this workspace"

[image]

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create that property in a WSDL file. Luckily the editor in Domino Designer shields you from the complexity. They are Composite Applications - Wire properties.

What the view publishes is inherit. What you publish needs to be defined as Wire property.